# MySQL, change true values to false and false values to true. How?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, liquibase

I need to change a column in a table in my database so that the values in the column that are currently true change to false, and the values that were false before to true.

Before:
Value A: false
Value B: true

After:
Value A: true
Value B: false

How do I do this? Trying to write a liquibase migration for this. I first thought of something like:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET columnA = false where columnA = true,
SET columnA = true where columnA = false;
```

But I realized that if I first change the true values to false, then all values will be false, and then MySQL will flip everything from false to true. Obviously not what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: `SET columnA = !columnA`

Answer (score 3):

You can make a `CASE WHEN`

```
UPDATE tableA SET columnA = CASE columna WHEN false then  true
ELSE false ENd;
```

If you have more nested conditions, it is not problem to expand the conditions

Answer (score 1):

Applying the `NOT` on each of your rows will solve your problem:

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET columnA = NOT columnA
```